# Round Brackets vs Curly Brackets on constructor calling

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-traits

Following codes work as expected with results:

```
ASM generation compiler returned: 0
Execution build compiler returned: 0
Program returned: 0
same
same
same
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct Test {
    Test() {
        std::cout << "Test ctor\n";
    }
    int func() {
        return 1;
    }
};

int main() {
    if (std::is_same_v<decltype(std::add_rvalue_reference<Test>::type{}.func()),int>) {
        std::cout <<"same\n";
    } else {
        std::cout <<"different\n";
    }
    if (std::is_same_v<decltype(Test().func()),int>) {
        std::cout <<"same\n";
    } else {
        std::cout <<"different\n";
    }
    if (std::is_same_v<decltype(std::type_identity<Test>::type().func()),int>) {
        std::cout <<"same\n";
    } else {
        std::cout <<"different\n";
    }
}
```

However, if I replace `std::add_rvalue_reference<Test>::type{}` with `std::add_rvalue_reference<Test>::type()`, the following compilation errors are generated:

```
<source>:14:33: error: reference to type 'Test' requires an initializer
    if (std::is_same_v<decltype(std::add_rvalue_reference<Test>::type().func()),int>) {
                                ^
1 error generated.
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>:14:33: error: reference to type 'Test' requires an initializer
    if (std::is_same_v<decltype(std::add_rvalue_reference<Test>::type().func()),int>) {
                                ^
1 error generated.
Execution build compiler returned: 1
```

Does anyone know what is causing `std::add_rvalue_reference<Test>::type()` to fail to call the constructor of `Test`, while `Test()` and `std::type_identity<Test>::type()` are fine?

Comment: You cant value-initialize a reference type

Comment: @JeJo it is not MVP. But you are right that `declval` is the way to go

Comment: I wonder why should a reference be default constructible with curly braces `{}`. Is it allowed in unevaluated contexts?!

Comment: I wonder why should a reference be default constructible with curly braces `{}`. Is it allowed in unevaluated contexts?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@[RemyLebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau) is right. It is not allowed to value-initialize a reference, while list-initializing a reference from `{}` works by creating a temporary.

[[dcl.init]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.init#8):

> A program that calls for default-initialization or value-initialization of an entity of reference type is ill-formed.

[[dcl.init.list]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.init#list-3.5):

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is defined as follows:
>
> - [...]
> - Otherwise, if `T` is a reference type, a prvalue temporary of the type referenced by `T` is list-initialized, and the reference is bound to that temporary.